# Pandas create column containing a row count

Tags: python, pandas

How can this query be reproduced in pandas?

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table t1 WHERE t1.full_name = t2.full_name) FROM table t2;
```

I want to count the number of rows that have the same value and save the value to the data frame.

What I tried until now is

```
df.full_name.values_count()
```

Which returns me a list of unique values, I then tried to merge it to the original database (with df.merge) but had no luck.

Comment: if you just want unique values then `df.full_name.unique()` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, wrap the value counts (which is a Series) in a DataFrame.

```
counts = pd.DataFrame(df['full_name'].value_counts(), columns=['num_unique'])
```

Then, merge, left on the original column, and right on the index.

```
df = df.merge(counts, left_on=['full_name'], right_index=True)
```